# How to SET_JOB in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks

Currently, I am transferring database from Oracle to Postgres, but I am having trouble converting

```sql
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_NAME => THE_JOB_NAME,
             ARGUMENT_NAME => 'in_study_count', ARGUMENT_VALUE => IN_STUDY_COUNT)
```

to Postgres, but I can't map `DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` with a Postgres equivalent solution. I recently worked with Postgres, so I don't have much experience with this. Hope everybody help please.

Comment: There is no built-in scheduler in Postgres. So there is no equivalent for the `dbms_scheduler` package to begin with. You could install [pg_cron](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/09/09/pgcron-run-periodic-jobs-in-postgres/) if you want to

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in his comment, there is no built-in scheduler in Postgres.

There is a commercial product named [EDB Postgres Advanced Server](https://www.enterprisedb.com/products/edb-postgres-advanced-server-secure-ha-oracle-compatible) which extends PorsgreSQL and provides extra functionalities for users migrating from Oracle, including a [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/database-compatibility-for-oracle-developers-guide/9.5/Database_Compatibility_for_Oracle_Developers_Guide.1.201.html) package which does have a `SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(job_name, argument_position, argument_value)` procedure, just like the Oracle package.

However, if you want to remain with the standard Open Source PostgreSQL database, installing [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) is probably your best option (as also mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name).